# How would you go through a string and be able to pull out numbers using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, database, web-scraping

So i would need a check with regex on multiple things. The names could look like this, so i would be searching the string of the key name.

```
name: 'Pop Icons #23 Paulie Pigeon Pinstripe Jersey NYCC'
 or 
name: 'Pop Marvel 80th 526 Captain Marvel / Mar-Vell First Appearance'
 or
name: 'Pop 2001: A Space Odyssey #823 Dr. Frank Poole' 
 or 
name: '389 Blue-Eyes White Dragon'
 or 
name: 'Pop Up Movie Town #05 Kevin with Up House'
```

what i currently have is

```
var numbers = /#[1-9]\d*\b/g;
var matchNumber = title.splitTitle.match(numbers);

return {
  number: matchNumber && matchNumber[0],
  name: title.splitTitle,
  image: title.image,
};
```

Above, title has what is called splitTitle and image so its an object that looks like this

```
title: {
  splitTitle: 'Pop Marvel 80th 526 Captain Marvel / Mar-Vell First Appearance'
  image: '*string that links to an image of the funko pop'
```

that currently can only get me the funko numbers if there is a '#' in front of the number. I would need to be able to get the number for the funko pop tho in all those types of strings above. I wouldnt need the extra as in Pop 2001 since that is just the year. I am trying to build out a funko database and need just the actual funko pop number.  One thought i have is making sure the funko pop digit is not 4 digits in length as that would make it most likely the year, and from searching online it does not appear that funko pop #s are bigger than 3 digits. But then that would lead something like 80th which is just the series getting pulled as well since its less than 4 digits. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: If you want the number only, you could use a capture group `#([1-9]\d*)\b` https://regex101.com/r/oFKJ2X/1

Comment: Could you indicate explicitly what the output for each input is supposed to be?

Comment: @TedBrownlow, yes so each output should be an object like this 
{
number: 526,
name: Pop Marvel 80th 526 Captain Marvel / Mar-Vell First Appearance,
image: *link to image*
}

but it would have to be able to work for all those different strings as the website i am pulling from is not constructed the same throughout each funko pop series

Comment: Can there only be a single occurrence of  a number in the format `#23`

Comment: @Thefourthbird i would need just the funko pop #, i wouldnt need the date number or the series number, i.e 2001, or 80th. just the funko # like 23, or 526.

Comment: @MattVolonnino Perhaps like this https://ideone.com/1yjT9S

Comment: @Thefourthbird i would still need the funko numbers for all the strings tho. I wouldnt want it to have "". I would need them all to have their associated number in the name string

Comment: @MattVolonnino Pehaps you can exclude the numbers that are preceded or followed by certain characters. Like for example `\b\d{1,3}\b(?!:)` https://regex101.com/r/txZT7z/1 It will work without the `(?!:)` but that is just as an example to exclude matches.

Comment: There are no links to images in the  text in your question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that seems to work, awesome! thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries `\b` and match 1 to 3 digits.

```
\b\d{1,3}\b
```

If there can not be a `:` after it, you can use a negative lookahead `(?!:)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/txZT7z/1)

```js
[
  "Pop Icons #23 Paulie Pigeon Pinstripe Jersey NYCC",
  "Pop Marvel 80th 526 Captain Marvel / Mar-Vell First Appearance",
  "Pop 2001: A Space Odyssey #823 Dr. Frank Poole",
  "389 Blue-Eyes White Dragon",
  "Pop Up Movie Town #05 Kevin with Up House",
  "test 42:"
].forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(/\b\d{1,3}\b(?!:)/);
  console.log(m ? `${m[0]} --> match` : `${s} --> no match`);
});
```